# Is it possible to reuse the exact same controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a RESTFUL API call through `controller`. The API response returns a `token` which is used for every subsequent API call. I wish to keep that data in the `controller` and it can be used for different `function` in the `controller`. But it seems like in the `route` function, the new `controller` instance will always be instantiated, is it possible to using the exact same `controller` across these `route`? 
For example, I have 3 `funcitons` in the `tenable controller`, I wish these 3 functions access to the same instance of `controller`

```
Route::get('/example','Tenable@sendReport');
Route::get('/posts/addscan','Tenable@addScan');
Route::get('/posts/scanreport','Tenable@addScan');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because a PHP Web Application "lives" for one request, which means after the request is processed, all data will be deleted - you can't save Data between 2 requests in PHP Itself, thats why you have to use SQL / Sessions / Cookies / Caching / Files.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data along with url or store it as a session variable or create a new migration for a table and store it there